# Arreglo. Máximo. mínimo, promedio y suma

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Segundo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

        double[]elementos = {3.3,1.2,4.6,8.9,10,14,13.2,11.8,9.9,1};
        double suma = 0;
        double max = 8;
        double min = 1;
        double promedio = 0;
        for (int i=0 ; i < elementos.length; i++){
            suma = suma + elementos [i];
        if(elementos[i] < min) {
            min = elementos [i];
        min = max = elementos[0];
        } else if(elementos [i]>max) {
            max = elementos [i];
        }
        promedio = suma / (double)elementos.length;
        System.out.println("la suma es " +suma+ "el promedio es " +promedio+ "el maximo es" +max+ "el minimo es " +min );
        }
    }
}
```

Si me pueden ayudar por favor. Necesito leer el siguiente arreglo: {3.3, 1.2, 4.6, 8.9, 10, 14, 13.2, 11.8, 9.9, 1} y  calcular: el valor máximo, el mínimo, el promedio y la
suma de los valores que están dentro del arreglo.

Comment: Y cual seria el problema que estas teniendo?

Comment: El único problema que tienes es que has puesto el ```System.out.println``` dentro del for... Te da lo mismo que la respuesta y el código esta bien. Te recomiendo tener un buen sistema de tabulación para leer mejor el código (si es que no lo tienes ya)

Answer (score 2):

Gente Ever compartió la solución utilizando Streams, ahora les voy a compartir la solución con java 7 por si les sirve para comprender la solución funcional anterior:

```
    double[] data = {3.3, 1.2, 4.6, 8.9, 10, 14, 13.2, 11.8, 9.9, 1};
    double total = 0;
    double maxValue = 0;
    double minValue = 100;
    double contador = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] < minValue) {
            minValue = data[i];
        }
        if (data[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = data[i];
        }
        total += data[i];
        contador ++;
    }

    System.out.println("Valor maximo: " + maxValue);
    System.out.println("Valor minino: " + minValue);
    System.out.println("Suma total: " + total);
    System.out.println("Promedio: " + total / contador);
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sería:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] data = { 3.3, 1.2, 4.6, 8.9, 10, 14, 13.2, 11.8, 9.9, 1 };

    double maxValue = Arrays.stream(data).max().getAsDouble();
    double minValue = Arrays.stream(data).min().getAsDouble();
    double total = Arrays.stream(data).sum();
    OptionalDouble promedio = Arrays.stream(data).average();

    System.out.println("Valor maximo: " + maxValue);
    System.out.println("Valor minino: " + minValue);
    System.out.println("Suma total: " + total);
    System.out.println("Promedio: " + (promedio.isPresent() ? promedio.getAsDouble() 
    : "0"));
 }
```

Salida:

```
Valor maximo: 14.0
Valor minino: 1.0
Suma total: 77.9
Promedio: 7.790000000000001
```

Comment: es programación funcional???

Comment: Java 8 con el bello uso de Streams, como te ahorras laburo.

Comment: @AntonioChamba exacto

Comment: Me sale error en los Arrays y en el OptionalDouble????